# c# put methods inside using statement possible?

Tags: c#, .net

im trying some different approach. Im not sure if its possible to place using() statement above methods or is there other way around.

```
public class Main 
{
    public Main() 
    {
      using(Type t = new Type) 
      {
        public void SomeFunction() {
             t.toString()}
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: If this did work what would be the scope of `t` and when would it get created and disposed? just the single function? If so why not just put it inside the function?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That is not possible, but you can do that like this:

```
 using(Type t = new Type) 
 {
    SomeFunction(t);
 }

 public void SomeFunction(Type tType) 
 {
    tType.ToString();
 }
```

**Note :** The `t` will be transferred to `SomeFunction()` and will be disposed at `}` of using block if the Class `Type` implements `IDisposible`, Since  [Using](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/yh598w02.aspx) statement calls the Dispose method on the object in the correct way, and (when you use it as shown earlier) it also causes the object itself to go out of scope as soon as Dispose is called

Comment: is it possible to put the whole class under using statement?.

Comment: No but You can Create its object as using variable; again note the class should implement  IDisposible

Comment: Beginning with C# 8.0, you can ignore the use of braces for Using statement.

Comment: @MajidShahabfar If we ignore the braces for using statement where will the statement end - I mean at what point the object t (in the above example, for instance) will be disposed?

Comment: @nam At the end of the scope of the variable t (which is here the end of the method), the Dispose method is invoked.